# How to add data in table dynamically in django?

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have following two models in my `models.py`.

```
class Book(models.Model):
    book_id = models.AutoField
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    book_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.AutoField
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author_description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

I want whenever I add new row in `Book` table, it automatically do entry in `Author` table ( Only author_id and author_name, author_description i will add manually ) for every unique author.
How to do it?

Comment: where is where views.py to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, in some different way.I suggest you you these ways:

1. Overwrite `Save` method of `Book` model. (Using `Save` method)
2. Send `Signal` to `Author` model for create `Author` object.

Now, I implement second way:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def create_author(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        author = Author.objects.create(id=your_id,author_name=your_author_name,author_description=your_author_description)
        Book.objects.objects.filter(pk=instance.id).update(author=author)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Book)
def save_author(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.author.save()
```